# '?' is not a valid resource character

Tags: android, xml

I need help adding '?' to my string values

```
<string name="use_budget_as_default_budget?">USE BUDGET AS DEFAULT BUDGET</string>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `use_budget_as_default_budget?` with `use_budget_as_default_budget`. You cannot use `?` in the name of a resource.